# After coming to landscape mode a white line appears between tableHeader and tableView?

Tags: ios, uideviceorientation

I made a tableView that loads data on segment button change.And it is working perfectly.
I had set tableView background color to some RGB values and applying custom header over it.My code is as follows:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BestFCell *bfcell=(BestFCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bestfcellIdentifier"];

    if (bfcell==nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BestFCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id temp in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([temp isKindOfClass:[BestFCell class]]) {
                bfcell=(BestFCell*)temp;
            }
        }
    }

    if (segmentCntr.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {
        bfcell.bestsize.text=[[[bestfiveArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bestbuysize%i",indexPath.row+1]] valueForKey:@"text"];
        bfcell.bestprice.text=[[[bestfiveArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bestbuyprice%i",indexPath.row+1]] valueForKey:@"text"];
    }else{
        bfcell.bestsize.text=[[[bestfiveArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bestsellsize%i",indexPath.row+1]] valueForKey:@"text"];
        bfcell.bestprice.text=[[[bestfiveArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bestsellprice%i",indexPath.row+1]] valueForKey:@"text"];
    }

    return bfcell;
}
```

//table custom header view .

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    BestFCell *bfcell=(BestFCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bestfcellIdentifier"];

    if (bfcell==nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BestFCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id temp in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([temp isKindOfClass:[BestFCell class]]) {
                bfcell=(BestFCell*)temp;
            }
        }
    }

    bfcell.bestsize.text=@"Best Buy Size";
    bfcell.bestprice.text=@"Best Buy Price";

    bfcell.bestsize.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    bfcell.bestprice.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];

    return bfcell;
}
```

and set footer to nil

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] init];
    return view;
}
```

all is fine but why white line appears on getting landscape mode.My screen shots are as follows :-
in portrait

[image: Portrait mode pic]

and in Landscape mode

[image: Landscape mode pic]

Thanks !..

Comment: can u make out which view is converted to line ? Or which control is missing, is that cell separator, dont think it is..

Comment: no cell separator,white line only appear when change in orientation,i.e from land to port Or from port to land.

Comment: a line automatically added between tableHeader and tableView.

Comment: Anything cant be added automatically, check hiding some views that you are showing, One of your view height is set to 1 after autoresize

Comment: try my given code you will easily understand there is nothing like another view than tableView

Comment: Can you join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family